# High risk clusters

Tags: r

This is a subjective question on developing a model in R.I am on an internship where I work for a company that identifies employees who are at a high risk of leaving a company on basis of data of previous employees who have left. For instance, I have been provided with the following data of employees who have quit the company:
1)Tenure Breakup (0 to 6 months, 6 to 12 months,.....)
2)Reasons for leaving ( Supervisior Dissatisfaction, Better opportunity etc...)
3)Gender 
4)Designated team at the time of leaving (Sales,Marketing)
5)Designation at the time of leaving etc
6)Age..........  and various other parameters.
(this data has been provided for 1 year i.e. data of all exits in the company for the past one year).

And I have been told to find out the high risk clusters from this data. For example what I did was that I made a matrix of tenure breakup vs reasons of leaving and store the counts in R. This helped me in identifying among different tenure breakups what was the main reason of leaving. But they do not want something like this. They want some clusters like some tenure break(say 12 to 24 months) within a team (say Sales) aged between 25-30 are at the most risk of leaving the company in future.

I have no clue how to derive such clusters in R.They are saying you can use some ggplots or something or some Linear regression analysis. Can anyone help me on that ?

Comment: I don't think that linear regression analysis would work on that problem because your problem is more of a classification problem than it is a prediction problem. maybe a neural network with a good codification of values would work better. I'm not expert, just a thought.

Comment: I think decision trees would work well here which are generalization of multiple if-then-else conditionals. The titanic dataset is very popular to test factors affecting survival rate which you can relate to employee turnover. You could use [this example](http://trevorstephens.com/kaggle-titanic-tutorial/r-part-3-decision-trees/) and adapt it as required.

Comment: Since this post is not really about programming I would suggest you move your question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). From a modeling perspective SVM, Decision Trees, Random Forests, or kNNs would all work for this problem.